# How to use case query SQL Server, with select field option query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table transaction(Trans)

```
noacc month date1 date2 date3
101    09    50    20    30
102    08    20    21    25
```

I want to make query sql when month is 09 select date3 and when month 08 select date2. I want to make query like this

```
Case When trans.month = 09 
THEN
(SELECT trans.date3 From trans)
ELSE
 (SELECT trans.date2 From trans)
END
FROM trans
```

Could you give me suggestion? Thank You Before

Comment: Which is data type for month column?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) which returns *a single, atomic value* (out of several possible alternatives). It can however **NOT** be used to conditionally execute one block of code - or another. For that, you must use `IF .... ELSE ....` constructs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select 
case when trans.month = 09 then trans.date3
     else trans.date2
end as [date]
FROM trans
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE  month 
        WHEN 9 THEN date3
        WHEN 8 THEN date2
    END as CalculatedMonth
FROM trans
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT case When trans.month = '09'  THEN date1  ELSE date2  end
FROM trans
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when trans.month=09 then date3 else date2 end  from tans
```

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of hard to guess what you want. Maybe provide a exemplary expected output?!

anyhow guessing you want this be evaluated row by row, the correct syntax is

```
Select
Case When trans.month = 09 
THEN
trans.date3
ELSE
trans.date2
END
AS Date
FROM trans;
```

you can express this even shorter as

```
Select IIF(month = 09, date3, date2) as Date
From trans
```